# How to get updated current date in django forms.DateInput value

Tags: javascript, django

How can I keep updated a current date in form field? I've tried to set date at views.py and forms.py, but in that case it saves date in cache only once (when I update index.wsgi) and then it's don't update date on every page reloads. Daily restart of the app is not an option. I can't believe javascript is the only way. I'm just stuck on it, help me, please.

How it looks like now: I have a form:

```
class AddRecordForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Journal
        fields = ['date']
        widgets = {
            'date': forms.DateInput(attrs={'type': 'date', 'class': 'form_input', 'value': date.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")}),
```

From this model:

```
class Journal(models.Model):
    date = models.DateTimeField()
```

And resulting html:

```
<input type="date" name="date" class="form_input" value="2020-01-17" required="" id="id_date">
```

Looks good, but if I go to the page tomorrow it will still be 2020-01-17. But it should be 2020-01-18 and so on. Date in form updates only after app reload (touch index.wsgi).

UPD: As it turned out, frontend way is only way. Have solved the issue in JS:

```
    var now = new Date();
    var day = ("0" + now.getDate()).slice(-2);
    var month = ("0" + (now.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
    var today = now.getFullYear()+"-"+(month)+"-"+(day) ;
    $("#id_date").val(today);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to use a frontend component

i.e A Date/Time picker as opposed to setting the value on the backend since by the time the template is rendered that date/time becomes invalid (In your case the next day).

`form.py`

```py
class AddRecordForm(forms.ModelForm):
    date = forms.DateTimeField(
        input_formats=['%d/%m/%Y %H:%M'],
        widget=forms.DateInput(
           attrs={
                'type': 'date', 
                'class': 'form_input',
           },
        ),
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Journal
        fields = ['date']
```

`form.html`

```
{{ form.date.id_for_label }}

<script>
  $(function () {
    $("#{{ form.date.id_for_label }}").datetimepicker({
      format: 'd/m/Y H:i',
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Some helpful examples on how to add DateTimePicker to your application https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2019/01/03/how-to-use-date-picker-with-django.html

Comment: I believe you're right. Probably there are no ways to do it on backend. Have done it this way.